# XCode Project encompassing Python2 and Python3

Tags: python, xcode, pymol

Hi I'm trying to write two python scripts for one project.  My goal is to have the front end of some analysis done in python3 with the output of many text files (completed).  The back-end of analysis will read text files and interface with PyMOL, which is python2 dependent (which I did not realize).  Using Xcode, or something else if Xcode is poorly equipped for this, can I run my 2 scripts consecutively as one project? Conceptually this seems simple but I have been unable to manage it.

Essentially I would like this in Xcode:

**Project**

```
    Python3 script
    Python2 script
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Xcode is not a Python IDE. It can open and edit Python files, but that's about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode is not a Python IDE*. It can open and edit Python files, but that's about it. Previous versions of Xcode included support for many programming languages, but now it is limited to just four: C, C++, Objective-C, and Swift. I recommend that you download a Python IDE instead of Xcode. There are many to choose from, and most run on Mac.

`*` - Well, technically you could set up Xcode to run Python by setting up the project to use an external build system. But that's like using a nuke to swat a fly -- you should use dedicated Python tools instead.

Comment: @user3430339 If this helped you, please upvote and accept my answer (click the checkmark underneath the arrows).